# Regex - how to match everything except a particular pattern

Tags: regex, ssl, apache-config

I'm using Apache and I want to redirect all received request to the ssl virtual host.

So I have the following line in the regular http virtual host:

RedirectMatch (.*) https://www.mydomain.com$1

which basicaly replace $1 by everything.

It works perfectly.  But now, I need to access a particular CGI that cannot be on the SSL virtual host.  So I would like to redirect all request, except the following:

"http://www.mydomain.com/mycgi/cgi.php"

I have search on this forum and found some post concerning regex exclusion, but none is working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Alain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache 2.2 and later has negative lookahead support in regular expressions. If you are using Apache 2.2 or later this should work:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(?!mycgi/cgi.php)(.*) https://www.mydomain.com/$1
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It works perfectly.  You resolved in less then 30 minutes what I was working on for almost 8 hours now!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the RedirectMatch is a [short-circuit sorta deal](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#).  What this means, is that if you put another RedirectMatch ahead of your match-all, only the first match will execute. so something like...

```
RedirectMatch (/mycgi/cgi.php) http://www.mydomain.com$1 
RedirectMatch (.*) https://www.mydomain.com$1
```

Comment: +1 You beat me by a few seconds. Your first rule should redirect to 'http' and you might want to add a leading '/' to it as well.

Comment: Won't that first rule result in a redirect loop?

Comment: Wow... it was fast!!!  But unfortunately by putting this line in my "normal non SSL" virtual host, it does not work.  Firefox give me that error: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
 And I think this is normal because we ask Apache to do a redirect.  So Apache receive the request, match it against the first regex then redirect to himself, match again, and so on.  Your idea about that?
I tryed to place the line in my SSL virtual server but it is ignored. Alain

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, but what if tomorrow there will be another exception? You'll get a fat, hard understand regex. Is better (easier to understand and maintain) to use an *If* directive expression with Apache internal variables.

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/mycgi/cgi.php$# && \
     %{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/anothercgi/cgi.php$#">
    RedirectPermanent / https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}
</If>
```